# Leaving space blank in a two dimenional array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

so I'm just starting a pretty simple project for school in which I want to create a booking system for a stadium. I've got a twoD array that will create a simple 7X10 array. However, I want to leave some space in the middle of the array that would represent the pitch/field in the stadium. I'm wondering how to do this?

I'm thinking an array inside an array if that is possible?

This is my code so far(got most of it from another question on here):

```
package FootballMatch;

public class Seats {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("\t\t Stadium Seating \n");

    int seatArray[][]= new int[10][7];
    int i, x, y = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for(x = 0; x < 7; x++) {

            seatArray[i][x] = y;
            y++;
        }   //  end inner for
    }   //  end outer for

    for(int[] row : seatArray) {

        printRow(row);
    }


}   //  end of main

public static void printRow(int[] row) {
    for (int i : row) {

        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" \t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

output:

```
`Stadium Seating 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30  31  32  33  34  35  
36  37  38  39  40  41  42  
43  44  45  46  47  48  49  
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  
57  58  59  60  61  62  63  
64  65  66  67  68  69  70`
```

So i want to have every 3rd to 5th number in the third to eight row of the array invisible, like this:

```
`Stadium Seating 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  _   _   _   20  21  
22  23  _   _   _   27  28  
29  30  _   _   _   34  35  
36  37  _   _   _   41  42  
43  44  _   _   _   48  49  
50  51  _   _   _   55  56  
57  58 59   60  61  62  63  
64  65  66  67  68  69  70`
```

Note all of these numbers will probably be changed to 'x' in the finished program. 'x' meaning the seat is available and an empty space meaning its the field!

Comment: Use an if statement, set the value to 0, and `if(val = 0)` print an X instead of the number?

Comment: IMO a better way to solve your problem would be to create a `Seat` class, which contains properties like soldStatus, price, etc. Then you could make an array of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of ControlAltDel's suggestion, a well designed answer to this problem (that also allows for later expansion) is to create a `Seat` Class to represent a single seat.

```
public class Seat{

    private int index;  //-1 if not available, > 0 otherwise
    private boolean available;

    /** Creates an available seat with index i. i > 0. */
    public Seat(int i){
        index = i;
        available = true;
    }

    /** Creates a non-available seat. */
    public Seat(){
        index = -1;
        available = false;
    }

    /** Return a string representation of this Seat. Its index if available, - otherwise */
    public String toString(){
        if(available) return index + "";
        else return "-";
    }
}
```

Then you can create a matrix of `Seat`s that represents your stadium:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("\t\t Stadium Seating \n");

    Seat seatArray[][]= new Seat[10][7];
    int i, x, y = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            if(i >= 2 && i <= 7 && x >= 2 && x <= 4){
                seatArray[i][x] = new Seat(); //Not available seat
            } else {
                seatArray[i][x] = new Seat(y);
            }
            y++;
        }
    }

    for(Seat[] row : seatArray){ printRow(row); }
}
public static void printRow(Seat[] row) {
    for (Seat s : row) {

        System.out.print(s); //toString method called implicitly here.
        System.out.print(" \t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it to a separate class! However, now I get an error in the toString method telling me I cannot convert index(int) to a String (because we're returning a '-'). Any ideas? I appreciate this btw!

Comment: Yeah, just add the empty string, it'll convert for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an boolean array to indicate that those positions can be occupied by a person.

In order to do this, you have to change your printing method. You have to use a code like:

```
// You must set canSeat at your will (true and false).
public static void print(int[][] seatArray, Boolean canSeat[][]) {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            if(canSeat[i][x])
                System.out.print(seatArray[i][x]);
            else
                System.out.print("  ");
            System.out.print(" \t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So he need two arrays? One for `can be booked` and one for `is currently booked`?

Comment: Well, the fist one (i.e. seatArray) is already there. He has to add only the second one, but this is not the unique solution. If he wants to keep the seatArray intact, I think it's good to use a second array to keep where a person can seat or not.

Comment: He can even use an array of integer instead of boolean and he can set some states, that is, 0 for stadium, 1 for seat taken, 2 for seat not taken, etc.

Comment: Ok, so when I change my print method to that and make my boolean array canSeat I get this error in the for loop inside my main.. "
The method print(int[][], Boolean[][]) in the type Seats is not applicable for the arguments (int[])"

Comment: Of course you get this error. You must adapt things to your code.